# Creating methods on the fly for a class instance

Tags: python

The following program is unable to create a function of a class

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name

    def read_name(self):
        return self.name

# First argument should be a ref to class
def callback(fcn, arg):
    fcn.name=arg

# Create a instance of class
a = MyClass("Blue")

# Lets add new member functions
setattr(a, 'callback1', callback)  
setattr(a, 'callback2', callback)  

print a.read_name()

print a.callback1("purple")    #! FAILS
print a.callback2("cyan")  #! FAILS
```

What is the right way of creating a class member function automatically?

I want to create 'N' callback functions, they all will modify some common/uncommon class data (A shared dict)

EDIT 1

I wish to collect information from 'N' separate/parallel threads by passing callback functions. I do not know beforehand how many callback functions I need thus I want to create them on fly.

EDIT 2

I have a dictionary(d) where I am storing the information of different processes. The dictionary(d) is accessed within the callback. But because the same `callback` function is called at different threads, the dictionary data gets garbled. As a quickfix, I thought of creating separate callbacks.

Answer (score 3):

If you know what you're doing, you'd want to try

```
import types
setattr(a, 'callback1', types.MethodType(callback, a, MyClass))
```

Comment: Or as an alternative that also works in python 3: `setattr(a, 'callback1', callback.__get__(a))`

Answer (score 1):

You can't add a class method to an instance; you have to add it to the class:

```
setattr(MyClass, 'callback1', callback)
```

But it's still a terrible idea. Why would you want this functionality?

Edit: keep your callbacks in a container instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, name=""):
        self.name = name
        self.callbacks = []

    def callback(self, idx, arg):
        self.callbacks[idx](self, arg)

# First argument should be a ref to class
def callback(fcn, arg):
    fcn.name=arg

# Create a instance of class
a = MyClass("Blue")

# Lets add new member functions
a.callbacks.append(callback)
a.callbacks.append(callback)

print a.name
a.callback(0, "purple")
print a.name
a.callback(1, "cyan")
print a.name
```

Comment: It may be a way to do dynamic AOT, or a way to alter a class during testing to produce a semi-mock.

Comment: If you do know know how many of something you will have then you should use a single container, like a list. `self.callbacks = []` ... `for callback in a.callbacks: callback()`.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I should append a list with callbacks? Would you elaborate on that?

Comment: _"You can't add a class method to an instance."_ Nowhere in the question does OP mention a class method, and adding (normal) methods to instances is very much possible.

Comment: That's exactly right ... or use a dictionary if you want to index by name or any other container type.

Answer (score 1):

In short: when grafting a method, assign it to the class, not to the instance.

Here's an elucidating example.

```
class A(object):
    """As trivial as a class can get."""
    def foo(self):
        return self.bar(1) + self.baz()

# Rework everything!

def new_bar(self, x):
    return 'I got %r' % x

def new_baz(self):
    return ' and I\'m okay!'

A.bar = new_bar
A.baz = new_baz

print A().foo()
```

Now grafting method to an *instance*.

```
a = A()

# An instance attribute is a bound method;
# when we replace it with a function, we lose access to self.
a.bar = lambda x: x * 100

A.baz = lambda self: 42

assert a.foo() == 142

# We can do better, though.
from types import MethodType

a2 = A()
a2.foo = MethodType(lambda self: 'I know myself, my class is %s' % self.__class__.__name__, a2)
print a2.foo()
```

Note how you don't need `setattr` to set an attribute, even an unknown attribute. You may remember that you don't use `setattr` in `__init__` either.

Comment: Wow. Adding properties to an instance is that simple.. didn't look right at first.